# Dealing with Managed Objects between two MVC's with one database

Tags: ios, core-data, object, managed

Current Setup:
MVC-1, onViewDidLoad, creates a Managed Object, fetches data from the Managed Object and updates various UI elements.

MVC-2: Same exact setup. I copied and pasted the same code from MVC-1 into MVC-2.

Issues I am seeing:
After launch and opening MVC-1, all the code is executed without any errors. The ManagedObject is created, the fetch requests on the ManageObjectContext work and the UI is properly updated. However, when switching to MVC-2 it seems that none of the data, that MVC-2 is suppose to fetch, is actually being updated. All the UI Elements in MVC-2 have the same data from the last time the application was launched.

Furthermore, if I launch the application and open MVC-2 first I get the same results, only MVC-1 does not appear to be updated this time around.

What is it that I am over looking? I have explicit saves to the database being made. I am (at least I think I am) creating two different ManagedObjects. Do I need to somehow close one before creating the other? Any advice would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How many managed objects contexts are you using?

Comment: One in each MVC. Each one is a Private Property of its MVC and is instantiated onViewDidLoad. Also, because I copied the code from one MVC to the other, they are named the same. Hope that helps.

Comment: I did some research on Apple's dev site, I think the issue might have something to do with refreshing the contexts. I am unsure about that though, and I'm a little confused on how to manage the refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I was saving the MOC, however I was not writing the `NSManagedDocument` to disk (I am using a `ManagedDocument` as a container for the Core Data database).

So naturally, when I switched to the MVC-2 I would not have the updated data.

I now save the MOC, write the MD to disk and close the MD at `viewWillDisappear`.

Thanks for the help gusy.